# Можно ли добавить текст в диалог, который открывается в рамках кнопки InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: python, telebot

Есть инлайн-кнопка, которая открывает диалог с пользователем телеграм.
button_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", url ="https://t.me/XXX")

Есть ли какие-то способы предзаполнить текст, который будет отправлен после открытия диалога?
Например, добавить текст "Хотел бы записаться на курсы".

Comment: Нет, "предзаполнить" отправляемый пользователю текст нельзя. Используйте общения через бота

Comment: Поняла. Спасибо!